# Change import statements dynamically with shell script

Tags: shell, sed, grep

Background

I have a folder (called classes) in which I have multiple files. I need to write a shell script that goes through all the java files and change the import statement.

**Example**

```
 classes
 │  ├── Context.java
 │  |── abc.java
 │  |── cde.java
 │  ├── another.java
```

**Inside the `Context.java`, I have:**

```
import "../folder1/abc.java"
import "../cde.java"
```

**And some files has only a single import statement.**

The goal is to change import location from `../folder/abc.java` to `./abc.java`. And change `../cde.java` to `./cde.java`.

**What I have tried so far:**

```
for file in *.java; do 

    new_import=$(grep -h "import" $file | sed 's:.*/::' | perl -ne 'print "import \"./$_"')
```

So `new_import` variable can retrieve the file name and add import keyword to begining. Now I have to change the `import line`  using sed with the `new_import`.

```
   # Inside the same for loop.
   grep -h "import" $file | grep -v "@" | sed -i.bak "s:^.*import.*:$new_import:g"
```

This supposedly do what I need but not working. I receive `sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin` error. I tried retrieving the line that has `import` substring and replacing with the variable.

I am using mac computer.

Comment: Pretty much what it says in the error message: You're piping something into `sed` but then use `-i` which only makes sense in the context of modifying a *file* in-place. There is no file when you pipe something into its stdin. Either remove `-i` and redirect your final result into a different file or redirect what you'd otherwise feed into `sed` into a file and modify that one in-place with `sed -i`. Your call.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit how to do second option? i redirected everything into file but how to modify that one in-place?

Comment: Instead of doing `... | sed -i`, you do `... > some_result_file; sed -i some_result_file` (or new line instead of `;`, same thing in a script). The first option would've been to just do `... | sed > some_result_file` directly, which I'd say is slightly more elegant.

Comment: None of these solutions edits the original file as occurence occurs. I would like to make the in place changes inside the file as match occurs

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the pipeline you have now. `grep` will just give you matching lines as text, there is no way for subsequent commands to reconstruct the whole file from those. It probably makes more sense to incorporate what the two `grep`s do into the `sed` pattern.

Comment: Why so complicated?  What's wrong with just `perl -i -e 's=import "../folder1/abc.java"=import ".abc.java"=; s=import "../cde.java"=import "./cde.java"=' *.java` ?  (you could do the same with `sed -i ...` but perl is smarter about not touching files that haven't been changed).